# Speedtest.net shows slow download speed but task manager shows otherwise

Tags: isp

I got a new ISP which worked fine for more than 3 months but on the 9th day of lockdown, the speed reduced to 1/10th.

I blacklisted all of the other users but the speed remained slow. I then contacted the service provider and was advised to play a 4k video on Youtube and keep an eye on the Wi-Fi speed consumption but this time the speed was good.

The problem arises when the browsing suddenly slows down on various sites and most of the videos at various sites, no matter how low the resolution is, the video takes a lot of time to buffer or download.
I have tried restarting the router and changed the channel but the speed remained slow. I have a 2.4ghz router. I have also tried the speedtest on another device but showed the same speed.

Comment: Could be that the websites you visit have enforced some kind of bandwidth limitation, or their own ISP has, or the DNS you send your requests to. Try a different set of DNS IPs in your router preferences (choose 1.1.1.2, as primary, and 1.0.0.2 as secondary, for example; those are Cloudflare's DNS servers).

Comment: primary and secondary DNS server boxes are greyed out.

Comment: OK, so I suppose your ISP enforces his own, and you're stuck with them. You can try to bypass them by adding the DNS I gave you in your WiFI adapter properties in Windows, but it may not really help you if the bottleneck resides between your router and your ISP's DSLAM, for example, or between the relay and your ISP's servers. Worth a try, though.

Comment: did what you just advised, but did not affect the speed. When I contact the service provider, one of the representatives replied me with the excuse that due to lockdown, more people are using the internet which is putting excessive load on servers, while the other told me that task manager shows the speed I pay for when playing a 4k video on youtube. Is there something that I can tell them or do myself that would solve this problem?

Comment: Those are difficult circumstances, so I suppose there's not much either of us can do to speed things up. If you can play a 4k video on YT without too much of a hiccup, then I guess that's the best you can hope for at the moment. There must be moments during the day when less people are trying to connect to the Internet and download speed is up, but I suspect your ISP has put the clamp on its network, for the sake of all users. You are going to have to be patient...

Comment: What I do not understand is that when playing a 4k video on youtube, the task manager shows more than 10mbps but speed test shows slow speed at the same time, even if I check for speesdtest seconds after closing youtube.

Comment: ISPs have a way to devolve more bandwidth to certain activities, namely streaming videos from platform such as YT, Netflix and the like, because they've signed business agreements with those platforms, and they know that their customers wouldn't hesitate to switch teams if they can't watch their programmes with reasonable quality and comfort, so they adapt individual bandwidth caps, based on the IP address you're streaming video from. On the other hand, they can limit your bandwidth for other usage. 10Mbps is barely enough for 4k video streaming, but it allows for fast buffering on your end.

Comment: There could be a wide variety of things causing this, as demonstrated from the comments.  Is your WiFi radio's channel set to _auto_ or a specific channel _(radios should never be set to auto - for 2.4GHz, channels `1`, `6`, or `11` should be used; 5GHz radios should be set as high as possible, with `157` being ideal if in the US)_.  All ISPs bundle throughput limits by neighborhood area, and once that throughput pool usage by customers exceeds an arbitrary limit, the ISP will try to switch some customers over to a different switch [for lack of a better term] or will throttle if not available.